# Ruby How to access a "key" of a two-dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array like that which I use in f.select when updating a user profile

```
  SEX = [["Male", 'M'],
        ["Female", 'F']]
```

I'd use a hash but I couldn't make it work at all with a select thing. So I have a select dropdown with values "Male" and "Female" and it assigns a value of "M" or "F" to user variable :sex. Now, when showing the profile I need to output sex as a "key" here (Male or Female, not M/F). How can I access these "key" values besides making huge get_sex and other getters for bigger arrays methods which won't be DRY at all? What can I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `rassoc` method https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-rassoc

```
sex = [["Male", "M"], ["Female", "F"]]
sex.rassoc("M")
 => ["Male", "M"] 
sex.rassoc("M").first
 => "Male"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a hash together with the `options_for_select` helper:

```
options_for_select({ "Male" => "M", "Female" => "F" }, "M")
```

Additional documentation can be found [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select).

Comment: How can I use it with an existing hash though? I don't understand

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work

<%= f.label :sex %>
<%= f.options_for_select(User::SEX.map { |s| [s.key, s.value] }) %>

Comment: It says undefined method `key' for ["Male", "M"]:Array, even though it's a hash now. Weird

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) for clarity. But just like panmari indicated, that's the way to go.

To make his suggestion more flexible I recommend you create constants for male and female and passing them as a hash to the select helper.

Comment: I read it, but I still don't understand how to do this with an existing hash(if I do it like this: options_for_select({ "Basic" => "$20", "Plus" => "$40" }) how can I access the key value later then?)

Comment: You can only access the value in the controller and write a short conditional statement to figure out the key pair.